# Python - Get yahoo finance data and retaining the data identifier

Tags: python, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I am trying to download data from Yahoo Finance and I have the following code to accomplish this; the code works well.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

ticker=['CBRL','DRI','MSFT']

start_date = '2015-01-01'
end_date = '2016-06-30'

data=pd.DataFrame()

for x in ticker:
    panel_data = pdr.DataReader(x, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
    data = data.append(panel_data)
```

My only problem is that the above doesn't retain the stock identifiers, ie once I have all data in one dataframe, I can't which ticker symbol each series corresponds to. I have tried using `panel_data.to_frame()` after running all of the above, but nothing changes. I am still stuck with all the data, but no ticker identifiers for each of my rows. Can I please have someone's thoughts?

Comment: Would you be able to post a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Index                           High  Low   Open   Close  Volume   Adj Close
2015-01-02 00:00:00   142   137   142      139      282200   123
2015-01-05 00:00:00   139   137   138      137      315500   122